# Python: How to add path separator to beginning of path

Tags: python, path

I'm looking for the cleanest way to add a path separator to the beginning of a relative path if it's not already there.

So for example **my/path should** result in **/my/path/**.

The way I do it now is the following:

```
import os
os.sep+'my/path'
```

This approach works but when a non relative path is passed it will also add the separator which is something I want to avoid.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `os.path.join` with the root directory as its first argument.

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('/', '/tmp')
/tmp
>>> os.path.join('/', 'tmp')
/tmp
```